# What is the name of this UI component? (Caspio actions/logic builder)

Tags: terminology, component, logic, open-source

Caspio (and other software I've seen over the years) includes a visual method of defining logic as shown in the screenshot below.

- Does anyone know the name of this type of component?
- Does anyone know open source components that do something like this?
- Does anyone have opinions on alternate UIs for achieving this sort of "logic building" functionality? The only alternative I can think of is something like a visual flow chart, but that would take up quite a bit more space.

Caspio actions screenshot:
[image: Caspio actions screenshot]

Here is a screenshot from a [game prototype](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nnuSQvoroJo&t=224s) that uses the same type of component:
[image: Game screenshots]

The closest I can think of is a "query builder", but a query builder in my experience is more like just a "condition builder" for filtering data, which is just a subset of what this component does.

Comment: Hi. I think you're looking for [Visual Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_programming_language). e.g. [MIT App Inventor](https://github.com/mit-cml/appinventor-sources) looks like one Open Source project that includes something like that.

Answer (score 1):

- This is called a no-code logic builder. It can also be called Visual Programming as mentioned by @Wodin.
- Haven't used an opensource tool but here is a list: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/the-top-five-open-source-nocode-tools/. MIT Scratch; the no-code app builder by Tulip Interfaces ([tulip.co](https://tulip.co/platform/app-builder/)), [Unqork](https://www.unqork.com/), Bubble, Microsoft's Power Automate are some examples of no-code logic builders out there that you can look at for inspiration.
- Yep! it doesn't need to be a flow chart, there are horizontal (linear) ways of achieving this (check the examples above). The language is also very important - it should be in a way that people can think through it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If you strip down the visual treatment, it boils down to combinations of 3 components here.

- Multi-level accordion: This is the outer shell of the component, each level is indented visualise the nested structure of the code.
- Combo boxes: Combinations of combo boxes within, where the values can be changed.
- Buttons: for actions like adding new lines.